# CPCL to Automatically Feed to Tear Off

Tags: zebra-printers

I'm working on printing 1x3" label to a Zebra ZQ320 using C# and Xamarin Forms. Below is the code that I'm using to setup the print job and then generate the label. This code currently works great if I'm manually aligning the label properly and then printing, except for after the print job is complete, I have to press the feed button on the printer to feed to the tear off line on the label (which over time makes the label unaligned).

```
! UTILITIES
BAR-SENSE
SET-TOF 0
IN-MILLIMETERS
SETFF 0 2.5
PRINT

! 0 210 210 210 1 
TEXT 7 0 0 15 {_location} 
TEXT 7 0 450 15 {_minMax}
CENTER
TEXT 4 0 0 0 {_company}
TEXT 7 0 0 50 {_description}
BARCODE 128 2 2 40 0 85 {_materialNumber} 
TEXT 7 0 0 130 {_materialNumber}
FORM
PRINT
```

So, I have two questions:

1. Is there something I can modify about this print job to force the auto-alignment to the tear off line?
2. Is there a way to auto-align to the next feed line at the beginning of the print job? I would not want it to auto-align if it's currently at a good position.

I am using the following as reference for what commands are available: [Zebra CPCL Manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/printers/common/programming/cpcl-pm-en.pdf)

Comment: this  really has nothing to do with Xamarin Forms or C#.  I'd suggest first looking for a setting on the printer that will automatically feed to the perforation after each job.  If it can't do that, then look for a printer command that will do it instead.  If nothing else works, you can manually work out how many lines are on each sheet and then add enough blank lines to each job to reach the perforation.

Comment: Oops, I removed those tags (didn't mean to leave them in there). Also, I added a link to the manual I'm using. From what I understand, the SETFF command is supposed to do that after the FORM command is issued, but no matter what I change the first parameter, it never stops at the next perforation.